# Can autobahn.twisted.wamp.Application do pub/sub?

Tags: python, twisted, autobahn, wamp-protocol

I would like to use some pub/sub features along with rpc from autobahn.twisted.wamp.Application

I'd prefer not to make a ApplicationSession class if I can get by without doing so.

Can registered rpc methods cause client subscriptions and publish?
If they can, please show me how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, sure:

```
def onEvent(msg):
   print("got event: {}".format(msg))

@app.register('com.example.triggersubscribe')
def triggerSubscribe():
   yield app.session.subscribe(onEvent, 'com.example.topic1')
```

When `triggerSubscribe` is called (e.g. remotely from another WAMP component), the *callee* (the WAMP component exposing `com.example.triggersubscribe`) will dynamically subscribe to `com.example.topic1`.

You can publish from within a registered procedure also of course: `app.session.publish()`.

I have added the complete example (including JS client) [here](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/wamp/app/subscribe_upon_call).

Comment: How can you do this and have `triggerSubscribe` return a value back to the caller? Python forbids a `return` statement in a generator.

Comment: In Twisted/Python2, use `returnValue` (http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.html#returnValue). There are analog mechnisms for Trollius/Python2 and asyncio/Python3.