# Create a topic in an RPC handler

Tags: python, autobahn

Is it possible to create a topic on-the-fly in a handler to a remote procedure call? It seems calling `self.subscribe` in the handler does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, possible:

- [Can autobahn.twisted.wamp.Application do pub/sub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330339/can-autobahn-twisted-wamp-application-do-pub-sub)
- https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/wamp/app/subscribe_upon_call